# How to create critical section in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have multiple "threads", they are running with `forkIO`. And I need to deal with mutual access, typical critical section/lock because they will share common `Map`: some of them will modify it, another ones - will read it. What are the critical sections in Haskell for thread creating with `forkIO`: API, modules, libraries?

EDIT: and all this works under `Scotty`

Comment: "some of them will modify it" how?

Comment: actually few threads will mutate the map: a thread should check if the element exists in the map, then to make some work and to add it to the map. And if such element already exists, the work should not be done. So critical section will guarantee that race conditions wont happen. And critical requirement is good performance. But I am not sure about performance of STM

Comment: "will mutate the map" HOW????

Comment: @n.m. The previous comment seems to me to answer the "how" quite clearly. Basically he's sharing a memoization map, and the "how will it be mutated" is just "some workers will insert a key if it ain't already available".

Comment: Are you sure you need a locked thing? Perhaps the usual pure lazy memoization trie trick is good enough without any additional locking.

Comment: yes, with an insertion of new element. But I am interested in good performance.

Comment: @DanielWagner I am afraid of the case when one will check for existence, then second, both will find that the key is missing, so both will do the work and will insert the item under the same key, so one of them will be lost.

Comment: @DanielWagner, `atomicModifyIORef'` is another option when the `Map` doesn't need to be kept in sync with other shared state.

Comment: I do use already `atomicModifyIORef` but it's not enough to save me from the described situation: both will find that key is missing and one of them will rewrite already inserted by another one. It's a classical test-and-set

Comment: @Paul-AG With the usual pure lazy memoization trie trick, there is a few-cycles window where two threads both trying to use the same key may do extra work. It's a very small window (about as long as it takes to check a single tag word in memory and then immediately write to it) -- especially considering it must be hit by two threads both wanting the same key. I recommend trying it first, because it is conceptually very simple and requires almost no code on the part of the consumers, and waiting for performance problems before even bothering to check how often you hit this few-cycle window.

Comment: @Paul-AG, then you're using it wrong. `atomicModifyIORef mref $ \m -> case lookup k m of Nothing -> (insert k v m, Nothing); r -> (m, r)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner excuse me, Daniel, would you like to point out some link to read more about it, because I am afraid, it seems such approach is unknown to me

Comment: @dfeuer Hm, this makes sense! I forget about second item in the returning tuple

Comment: @Paul-AG e.g. [this package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.9/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html), or also browse the results from [this search](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=memoization+trie).

Comment: The only time that won't work is if you need `IO` to fill in the missing key, on which case your best bet is probably to use an `MVar` and `modifyMVar`.

Comment: Er, I meant `atomicModifyIORef'`, which is much less likely to leak memory than the lazier version.

Comment: @dfeuer I need IO to start a process and to save its handler in as the value in the map, but it should not be a problem bcz I can check if `atomicModifyIORef` was successful and to update the value (it's some record with handle in one of it's fields).

Comment: The main limitation of a lazy trie is that there's no way to clean up keys you don't need anymore or limit your structure's size.

Comment: @dfeuer it's important: I need to remove completed processes and "stale" ones. Your solution looks clean and simple from my POV: it's atomic test-and-set, what I need

Comment: @DanielWagner No it doesn't explain anything. "will insert a key" This will return a **new** Map. To actually mutate a variable you need something special that supports mutation. What? IORef? MVar? STM? **HOW** do you mutate? The answer very much depends on that.

Comment: @n.m. But the question is exactly how to mutate in the sense you are now explaining. So of course the question doesn't say how to mutate!

Comment: @DanielWagner I thougt the question is "What are the critical sections in Haskell" and not how to mutate, but I am known to be wrong occasionally.

Answer (score 5):

The goto library for concurrency in Haskell is [stm](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm). Instead of locking, operations on shared memory (your shared `Map`) can be organized in atomic transactions.

Comment: Am I right, that if 2 threads try to access shared object, STM will rollback transaction which means I will have 2 `Map` objects in the memory: for rollback and for attempt to modify?

Comment: @Paul-AG Yes, that is correct. Indeed, since we're talking about ephemeral situations here anyway, there are briefly almost certainly more than two: the original, one thread's modified version, and another thread's modified version. Of course all the usual laziness and sharing considerations apply; also almost certainly these three objects take significantly less than three times as much memory as any single one of them takes.

Comment: STM looks fine but I am not sure about performance: I will have a lot of requests, so.. may be simple locking mechanism will be faster

Comment: Nothing prevents you to have locks on top of stm. You are free to define any synchronization strategy you want.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia sure, but STM only starts to look good when you have multiple shared variables that need to be kept in sync. Otherwise you're paying a performance penalty for nothing. If it's just a cache, then an `IORef` (or perhaps `MVar`) seems like a better choice.

Answer (score 5):

An `MVar` is a mutable variable that is its own critical section.

```
takeMVar :: MVar a -> IO a 
-- Return the contents of the MVar. If the MVar is currently empty, takeMVar will
-- wait until it is full. After a takeMVar, the MVar is left empty.

putMVar :: MVar a -> a -> IO ()
-- Put a value into an MVar. If the MVar is currently full, putMVar will
-- wait until it becomes empty.
```

The takeMVar—update—putMVar of `MVar YourMapType` is basically all you need, unless there is a specific requirement that a map should be somehow available while it's being updated. In this case, you can use `MVar ()` as a mutex to control access to whatever you want.

Comment: It's usually better to use `modifyMVar` rather than taking and putting manually. It takes care of the (somewhat tricky) exception safety issues.

Comment: @dfeuer The docs say " This function is only atomic if there are no other producers for this MVar". I'm a bit confused by that. What does it mean exactly?

Comment: It means that a process could take the `MVar` (using `modifyMVar`) and some other process could put the `MVar` before the first process has a chance to do so. You need to impose some sort of discipline. Most commonly, that means always taking the `MVar` before putting it (e.g., using `modifyMVar`).